# image upload TypeError: Cannot read property 'path' of undefined

Tags: node.js, mongodb, vue.js

I have been trying to add a product with image to the mongoDB. Postman tests are success, but when i try to do it from frontend i get this error cannot read propery path. I know i am missing something since i cannot use v-model in my html file input. Can you please help?

frontend

```
<template>
  <div class="add-rope">
    <div class="add-rope-inner">
      <form @submit.prevent="handleSubmitForm"  enctype = "multipart/form-data">
        <h1>Add</h1>
        <input type="file" class="add-rope-input" placeholder="image"  name="image">
        <input type="text" class="add-rope-input" placeholder="Naslov" v-model="ropes.title">
        <input type="text" class="add-rope-input" placeholder="Promjer" v-model="ropes.diameter">
        <input type="number" class="add-rope-input" placeholder="cijena" v-model="ropes.price">
        <input type="number" class="add-rope-input" placeholder="mjerna jedinica" v-model="ropes.cartQuantity">
        <input type="text" class="add-rope-input" placeholder="kolicina u skladistu" v-model="ropes.totalQuantity">
        <textarea class="add-rope-textarea" placeholder="Opis" v-model="ropes.description"></textarea>
        <button class="add-rope-button">Dodaj</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import axios from "axios";
import router from "@/router";

export default {
  data() {
    return {
      ropes: {
        title: '',
        description: '',
        image:'',
        diameter: '',
        price: '',
        cartQuantity:'',
        totalQuantity: ''

      }
    }
  },
  methods: {

    async handleSubmitForm() {
      try {
        await axios.post('http://localhost:3000/api/ropes', this.ropes)
            .then(() => {
              this.$router.push('/crud')
              this.ropes = {
                title: '',
                description: '',
                image:'',
                diameter: '',
                price: '',
                cartQuantity:'',
                totalQuantity: ''
              }
              router.go(-1)
            })
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
      }
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

this is the backend part:

```
router.post('/', upload.single('image'), async (req, res) => {
    //create a new user
    console.log(req.file)
    const rope = new Rope({
        title: req.body.title,
        description: req.body.description,
        image: req.file.path,
        diameter: req.body.diameter,
        price: req.body.price,
        cartQuantity: req.body.cartQuantity,
        totalQuantity: req.body.totalQuantity
    });
    try {
        await rope.save();
        res.status(201).json(rope);
        console.log(req.body)
    } catch (err) {
        res.status(400).send(err);
    }
});
```

Comment: You do not attach the file to the request body, do you? Here is a tutorial, how you can add it to the form: https://serversideup.net/uploading-files-vuejs-axios/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `form data` for upload image, like this:

html:

```
<input @change="setPhoto" type="file" name="photo" id="photo"/>
```

method:

```
setPhoto(e) {
 this.photo = e.target.files[0] || e.dataTransfer.files[0];
 this.url = URL.createObjectURL(this.photo);
}
```

create form data:

```
let fd = new FormData();
fd.append("photo", this.photo);
```

Comment: can you show me how to implement form data in my code above... i am not sure how to do this?